# Badge 'Proofreader' is not awarded as stated in its description

Tags: support, badges, editing

The *Proofreader* badge's description reads

> Approved or rejected 100 suggested edits.

Right now, [9 users meet that condition](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats), however, only [7 users actually earned the badge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/badges/73/proofreader) (i.e., brasofilo and I did not).

Even if posts users wrote themself aren't considered (which may be the case for myself, because I remember approving/rejecting suggested edits of two or three of my own posts), I can't believe brasofilo did that more than 38 times (referring to his 138 suggested edits).

What am I not getting here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badge is for *approving* or *rejecting* suggestions. The [stats](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) show just reviews. If you *edit* a suggestion, you don’t approve or reject it, so this doesn’t count towards that badge. You need 4 more actions, brasofilo was even busier editing. :)

But please continue editing incomplete suggestions. The quality of our posts is more important than your badges.

See also: [Where is my Proofreader badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173439/where-is-my-proofreader-badge)

Comment: Ah, good to know how it really works. And, yes, will do (continue editing incomplete suggestions)!